# Sencha Touch 2 add icons to nestedlist

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am trying to add images to a nested list using the getItemTextTpl method of NestedList. Can you please take a look at the following code and let me know how to fix it? This was developed using Sencha Architect. Thanks for your help.

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.ListContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    alias: 'widget.listcontainer',

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        tpl: [
            ''
        ],
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'nestedlist',
                id: 'myList',
                itemId: 'mynestedlist4',
                detailCard: {
                    xtype: 'mytabs'
                },
                store: 'myStore',
                toolbar: {
                    xtype: 'titlebar',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    ui: 'dark'
                }
            }
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'getItemTextTpl',
                event: 'getItemTextTpl',
                delegate: '#myList'
            }
        ]
    },

    getItemTextTpl: function(node) {
        return '<img class="eventIcon" src="http://localhost/images/test.png">';

    }

});
```

Comment: 'please take a look at the following code and let me know how to fix it?'... What is to fix, what doesn't work ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul You're right, my question was pretty weak and should have included proper detail. Turns out I had to promote my NestedList to a top level component, then add a Basic Function to it in order to implement the getItemTextTpl

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.myList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.NestedList',
    alias: 'widget.mynestedlist',

    config: {
        id: 'myList',
        detailCard: {
            xtype: 'mytabs'
        },
        displayField: 'text',
        store: 'myStore'
    },

    getItemTextTpl: function(recordnode) {
        return '<img class="eventIcon" src="http://localhost/images/test.png">'; 
    }

});
```

Comment: Can you explain how did you do that in "Sencha Architect"?

Comment: Ok, I have found the answer by my self. To do that, you have to promote your Nested List to Class (right click on nested list and select `Promote To class`). And then you will have access to custom functions (section `Functions` in object inspector).

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip. [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) is a great way to add beautiful icons easily to you application.